# Show decrypted strings only for a specific customer

Tags: encryption, passwords, prestashop

I'm looking for the best way to show decrypted strings only to my customer, I don't want the programmer or database people to know the value of this strings.

First I think using the customer password to decrypt this strings but if the customer change or forgot his passwords the system will be not able to decrypted these strings.

I'm using PHP & PrestaShop.

Comment: What do you mean by "decrypted strings", what kind of information are you trying to encrypt/decrypt and where would it be displayed?

Comment: Are confidential information of the customer, so need a way to encrypt that information and only show them to that customer. So need to be encrypted on the database, also need that developers  can't decrypt it.

Comment: That sounds complicated. You would need to ask the customer for an encryption key (not stored in database, impossible to retrieve if he/she looses it) and then use openssl_encrypt() and openssl_decrypt() to store/retrieve the encrypted information using this key.

Comment: You can made php script and use on it ioncube. https://www.ioncube.com/